# Isomorphisms preserve order: the infinite case

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

Given a group $G$ and a isomorphism $\varphi: G \to H$, I know how to prove that $|x| = |\varphi(x)|$ in the finite case. If $|x| = n$, I prove that $\varphi(x^n) = \varphi(x)^n$, and since $x^n = e$,  $\varphi(x^n) = \varphi(e_G) = e_H$, so $\varphi(x)^n = e_H$, so $|\varphi(x)| \mid |n|$. On the flip side, let $m = |\varphi(x)|$. Then $\varphi(x)^m = e_H$. But then
$$
e_H = \varphi(x)^m = \varphi(x^m).
$$
As $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, it is injective; since $\varphi(x^m) = e_H = \varphi(e_G)$, we have $x^m = e_G$, so $|x| \mid |\varphi(x)|$, so $|x|=|\varphi(x)|$.

This proof does not generalize to the case where $|x|$ or $|\varphi(x)|$ are allowed to be infinite, however. I can't figure out how to prove the statement in that case. I could argue that the above shows that $|x|$ is finite if and only if $|\varphi(x)|$ is finite, so one is infinite if and only if the other is infinite. I don't think that proves the statement in general, however.

Comment: I don't understand why you would think that does not prove the statement. You proved that $x$ and $\varphi(x)$ have finite order if and only if the other does, and in that case the orders are equal. So in all cases you showed $|x|=|\varphi(x)|$.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to realize that infinite here means countable?

Comment: @CaptainLama I think that makes sense, thank you. So if one is finite, the other is finite. If one is not finite, the other is not finite by contraposition, and the proof is done. Is that the idea?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo I'm not fully sure I understand. Could you please say a bit more about this?

Comment: If they (orders) are both finite, they are equal. If they are both infinite, they are both countable, so equal again.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it useful to prove that the order of the element $x\in G$, where $G$ is a group, is the cardinality (finite or infinite) of $\langle x\rangle$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.

An isomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$ is a bijective map (so it preserves the cardinality of subsets) and $\varphi(\langle x\rangle)=\langle\varphi(x)\rangle$.

How do you prove the first statement? Consider the homomorphism $f_x\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ defined by $f_x(k)=x^k$. The image of $f_x$ is precisely $\langle x\rangle$.

If $x$ has infinite order, then $f_x$ is injective, so $\langle x\rangle$ is infinite.

Suppose $x$ has finite order $n$. Then, by definition, $x^n=e$ and for no integer $k$ with $0<k<n$ we have $x^k=e$.

The kernel of $f_x$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m>0$ and the minimum positive integer in $m\mathbb{Z}$ is $n$ by assumption. Therefore $m=n$.

From the homomorphism theorem it follows that $\langle x\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/\ker f_x=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which has $n$ elements.